# RXJS: Dispatch action in retryWhen

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have written a react, redux, rxjs application that fetches every 5 seconds data from the API. Every time the application is fetching I'm displaying a loading indicator.

If the call fails it will start with the `retryWhen` mechanism, and then I need to update the store from `loading` to `retrying` so i can update the view.

Currently I'm stuck because I don't know how to update the store from `retryWhen`.

#### App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchAdvertisement();
  }

  fetchAdvertisement = () => {
    console.log('Start advertisement call');
    console.log('---------------------------------------------');
    const { displayId, unitId } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchAdvertisement(displayId, unitId);
  };

  render() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>;
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  fetchAdvertisement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      displayId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      unitId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default App;
```

#### Action creators

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from 'modules/contants';

export function fetchAdvertisement(displayId, unitId) {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH, payload: { displayId, unitId } };
}

export function fetchAdvertisementSuccess(payload) {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload };
}

export function fetchAdvertisementRetrying() {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_RETRYING };
}

export function fetchAdvertisementFailed(payload) {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_FAILED, payload };
}
```

#### Epics

```
export const retryMechanism = ({
    scalingDuration = 1000,
    excludedStatusCodes = []
  } = {}) => attempts =>
    attempts.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => {
      // Update the store by dispatching the action creator fetchAdvertisementRetrying

      const retryAttempt = i + 1;
      if (excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)) {
        return _throw(error);
      }
      console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${scalingDuration * retryAttempt}s`);

      return timer(scalingDuration * retryAttempt);
    })
  );

export const fetchAdEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH).mergeMap(action =>
    ajax
      .getJSON(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/request-ad/${action.payload.displayId}`)
      .map(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          return fetchAdvertisementSuccess(response.data);
        }
      })
      .retryWhen(retryMechanism())
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of(fetchAdvertisementFailed(error.data));
      })
  );
```

#### Reducer

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from 'modules/contants';

const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH: {
      console.log('Loading');
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      return state;
    }

    case ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_RETRYING: {
      console.log('Retrying');
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      return state;
    }

    case ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_SUCCESS: {
      console.log('success');
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      return state;
    }

    case ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH_FAILED: {
      console.log('error');
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      return state;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how rxjs works, so a lot of this code looks foreign to me. A quick browse through the [rxjs middleware Epic documentation here](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) indicates that the middleware passes two parameters to your epic: `action$` and `store`. Thus, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
export const retryMechanism = (dispatch) => ({ scalingDuration = 1000, excludedStatusCodes = [] } = {}) => attempts =>
    attempts.pipe(mergeMap((error, i) => {
        // Let the store know i am retry-ing by calling the function fetchAdvertisementRetrying
        dispatch(fetchAdvertisementRetrying());
        const retryAttempt = i + 1;
        if (excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)) {
            return _throw(error);
        }
        console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${scalingDuration * retryAttempt}s`);
        return timer(scalingDuration * retryAttempt);
    })
);

export const fetchAdEpic = (action$, store) =>
    action$.ofType(ACTION_TYPES.ADVERTISEMENT_FETCH).mergeMap(action =>
        ajax
        .getJSON(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/request-ad/${action.payload.displayId}`)
        .map(response => {
            if (!response.data) {
                return fetchAdvertisementSuccess(response.data);
            }
        })
        .retryWhen(retryMechanism(store.dispatch)())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.of(fetchAdvertisementFailed(error.data));
        })
);
```

Note: (also from the docs) that the store provided to your epic is a light-weight version of the store, and not the full store object. The store provided only contains the methods `getState` and `dispatch`.